# FetchXML in .NET Core - CRM Web API

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, .net-core, dynamics-crm

I'm learning how to use CRM Web API with .NET Core to work with entities and I found this very useful [library](https://github.com/davidyack/Xrm.Tools.CRMWebAPI/tree/master/dotnet). There is an option to retrieve record data using `FetchXML`.

```
string fetchXml = "<fetch mapping='logical'><entity name='account'><attribute name='accountid'/><attribute name='name'/></entity></fetch>";
var fetchResults = await api.GetList("accounts", QueryOptions: new CRMGetListOptions() { FetchXml = fetchXml });
```

Is there any option how to compose more easily and elegantly the `fetchXML`, for example by using QueryExpression (`Microsoft.CrmSdk.CoreAssemblies`) or something similar?

Comment: what did you endup with?

Comment: Not really, I use the XrmToolBox FetchXML, although it is not what I wanted.

Answer (score 0):

1. Design the Advanced find query & download the fetchxml
2. Develop fetchxml queries using [XrmToolBox FetchXML builder](https://fxb.xrmtoolbox.com/)

You can use `QueryExpressionToFetchXmlRequest` to convert the QueryExpression into FetchXml.

[Read more](https://stackoverflow.com/q/54356648/7920473)

Comment: the QueryExpressionToFetchXmlRequest  would be good, but I can not use IOrganizationService in .NET Core so I don't know how to use it there and if is possible.

Answer (score 0):

I have found Mike Ochs's [FetchXmlWrapper](https://github.com/TheCRMLab/CRMFetchXmlWrapper) helpful in certain projects.

More info: https://www.cobalt.net/2014/06/25/performance-improvements-using-fetch-xml-wrapper/